# Azure SQL Database Geo Replication With Large Table

Tags: azure-sql-database, geo-replication

We are getting ready to move our non-Azure db to Azure Sql Database and are wanting to use Geo-Replication as a failover.

Our audit table has 130+ Million rows of data and so just wondering how long the seeding process will take?

Also do we have to wait for the seeding process to complete before we can open up our production App? If the seeding process has not completed and we start creating transactions in our primary db, what will happen to those transactions on the secondary DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time it takes is really dependent on a lot of factors, so it's going to hard to give you a solid answer. However, I can tell you that you can immediately make the database available before it completes the geo-replication setup. It's made so that you have access to the primary database the whole time.

Comment: Ok, that helps to know we can still use the primary while the secondary is being seeded.

Comment: The biggest factor for the time, beyond the size of your data, is the distance between data centers. Laws of physics get in the way of moving more thing faster over longer distances. That's about the biggest amount of help I can provide. I haven't seen published specs on it.